# Win7/Ubuntu dual booting: Black screen after reinstalling Ubuntu 10.10

Tags: 10.10, dual-boot, re-installation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

I've been experiencing this black screen after reinstalling ubuntu in a dual booting with Windows 7.

I've actually research on this site and on Google and I feel my scenario is a bit different.

First thing is that this is the third time I'm installing Ubuntu 10.10 with the same DVD, and this is the first time I'm seeing this.

On my previous intallation, I was running some database script and I noticed my machine was freezing. It took a long time, but I had no chance to restart it. So I  did a hard reboot (holding down the power button and press it again to start again). That puts me in front of the BusyBox screen, and I had to fix it with the liveCD (fsck /dev/sda4).

But after this I realized that the machine was pretty slow, and I thought something is wrong with the file system.

So I picked up the liveCD again and did a fresh installation of Ubuntu, but when I'm prompted to redraw the liveCD it turns black (2 times actually).
Now there is one thing I did notice that makes me doubt my installation proces. Most of the time I simply delete the partition and create a new one. But I've kept it this time and marked it to be formated. So I'm not sure on that one.

My machine comes with an `ATI` graphics card, and most of what I've read about online is about `NVIDIA drivers` (`nomodeset`).

Previously I never had to do that. Now what should I do? I'm writing this post from my Windows installation, wich booted normally, and where it doesn't seem like the graphic card is damaged or something.

Actually this laptop is a working machine. So i'm kinda hot here.

Thanks for reading this.

Comment: `but when I'm prompted to redraw the liveCD it turns black (2 times actually)`: Can you clarify this a bit? Because I don't really see what you mean here. I assumed you meant that you got a black screen when you took out the CD after the installation. But that seems a bit strange to me as simply rebooting the machine would have solved that problem.

Comment: just to be make sure you could check the dvd, make sure there aren't any problems that have risen with either the DVD or the drive. I for one have wasted lots of time looking for problems that turned out to be caused by a CD that had gone bad. It might seem pointless but on the other hand it's very easy to check.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!

Comment: [This answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it/162076#162076) should help you solve the problem.